# Is there any quantitative way to test the performance of AngularJs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to know is there any tools available which can test the performance of an AngularJs application quantitatively apart from chrome Batarang.

Comment: The browsers' built-in profiling tools are pretty quantitative. What metrics are you looking for? What did you try besides Batarang?

Comment: hi i have tried Firefox's Cleopatra plugin

Comment: and what did you find? You have to be more verbose than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This article "[AngularJS Performance in Large
  Applications](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications)"
  has mentioned [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/) and the Profiler in
  Chrome Dev Tools. It has also given some general guidelines
  for better AngularJS Performanace. They are real insights. Deserve reading. If you are doing a large web application using Angular and are suffering from slow performance problem, you can use these guidelines as a checklist.
- On the other hand, [this
  article](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/reactjs-vs-angular-js-performance-comparison-knockout#/)
  has resorted to manually coding and comparing the performance of
  three frameworks: React vs AngularJS vs KnockoutJS.
- [This article](http://voidcanvas.com/emberjs-vs-angularjs-performance-testing/) compares two frameworks: AngularJS vs EmberJS through manually coding and comparing. It is interesting that this comparison's result has clearly shown each framework's pros and cons.

  It has compared 3 aspects:

  1) Rendering;

  2) Data Binding;

  3) Operation flow.

  We can see these two frameworks'
  performance have shown big contrast because of their different
  algorithm. AngularJS is very slow in data binding because its dirty
  check algorithm, while EmberJS is slow in operation flow because each
  time an object changes, it calls the observer.

Hope these would help.